# Debug symbols for LLVM libraries?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, gdb, llvm, debug-symbols

I'm using the Ubuntu packages to develop against the LLVM libraries.  Here are the packages I have installed:

```
libllvm3.1
llvm-3.1
llvm-3.1-dev
llvm-3.1-runtime
llvm-3.1-source
```

'llvm-3.1-source' contains the source code, but as far as I can tell, none of them contain the debug symbols.  So when I get a segfault deep inside some LLVM code, I can't tell at what line of source code it occurs.

How do I get the debug symbols?

Answer (score 0):

LLVM is quick-and-easy to build from source. Download the source packages from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.2 and follow the instructions to build in debug mode. Then you can have full debugging capability into LLVM itself.